I passed edgecolor[s] for an unfilled marker
Matplotlib issued the message:
UserWarning: You passed a edgecolor/edgecolors
XXXX for an unfilled marker.  Matplotlib is
ignoring the edgecolor in favor of the
facecolor.

My marker is "+".  To me, it has no area, so I would expect "edge" to be relevant rather than "face".
Is this just a matter of "tomawto" vs. "tomayto"?  That is, does the message mean that it using my edge color specification?
It's hard for me to tell because I have a sequence of RGB values, one for each point, sampled from seaborn's deep colour palette.  Some of the points have the same RGB colour, depending on various other factors.
My plotting command is:
plt.scatter( df2plus.long_km, df2plus.lat_km, marker='+',
   fc='None', ec=df2plus.MMSIcolr, s=100, linewidth=1 )

df2plus is a dataframe where column long_km are the x-coordinates and lat_km are the y-coordinates.  Column MMSIcolr contains the RGB 3-tuples (one per row).

The warning says it is ignoring the edgecolor.  You can verify that it is ignoring the edgecolor by trying a simple example like plt.scatter([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], edgecolor='fuchsia', marker='+')

Well, the warning is very clear: the edgecolor is ignored.  It seems to be useful to show the warning, as this behavior isn't intuitive.  The reasoning why it happens like this, is hard to tell without a deep dive into the source code (and maybe also its history). Anyway, philosophy is out of scope for StackOverflow.

@RuthC: Better yet, repeating that command causes the colours to change even though the edgecolor specification does not.  I find it very odd that face color instead of edge color is used for lines. Exchanging the face color specification with the edge color specification yields the desired colours (as far as I can tell)

@JohanC: To me, it's confusing, but infinitely more informative than without the message.  I hope that this Q&A (or rather, the Q part for the moment) will confirm the meaning for others who are confused by the message.

There is a large comment in matplotlib's source.

There was a big discussion when it was done https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/17850

I think newcomers to Python and MatPlotLib need to tread carefully.  Following JohanC's link to the code, I tried to find out what "fill" meant from the scatter documentation.  That brought me back to a previous difficulty where the color parameter isn't explicitly listed as a parameter, and I followed the "Other Parameters" section, which linked to Collections properties page.  This is a massive apge, and a search for the whole word "color" yielded hundreds hits.

I appreciate the pointer to the previous discussion about the reasons for the current behavior.  I can't say that I follow it, but regardless of the historical reasons, I think it's inevitable that it will throw newcomers for a loop.  I can only hope that this SO question helps them.  Maybe the comments can be collected into an answer?

As explained in the comments under the posted question, the warning message is accurate.  This behaviour may be difficult to understand for newcomers, but is necessitated for reasons of backward compatibility.
With thanks to commentors johanC and RuthC.
